# echarts: How to use subscript/superscript (or latex/mathjax) in 3D axis labels?

Tags: javascript, echarts

How do I render superscript or subscript in a 3D chart?

Right now I'm doing like this:

```js
xAxis3D: { scale: true, gridIndex: 0, name: "f0" },
yAxis3D: { scale: true, gridIndex: 1, name: "f1" },
zAxis3D: { scale: true, girdIndex: 2, name: "f2" },
```

and the y-axis label in the plot looks like this:

[image]

**Instead of `f2`, is there any way I can label it like `f₂` (similar to `f<sub>2</sub>` in html)?**

**Also, is there any way to use latex or mathjax within echarts?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know Echarts doesn't have this or similar features. But even if it did, it’s not enough. Need improve the zRender (visualization engine) to support this feature.

I would to recommend for you to capture the values and replace to Unicode symbol in `formatter`, see example:

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
var chars = ['\u00BC', '\u00BD', '\u00BE', '\u2150', '\u2151', '\u2152'];
var option = {
  xAxis: [{
    data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: (val, idx) => chars[parseInt(val)],
    }
  }],
  yAxis: [{}],
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20]
  }]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Addition:

- [Online Converter LaTeX expression to Unicode](https://www.unicodeit.net/)
- [Ready to use library on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/latex-to-unicode)

P.S. Just for my: have you ever seen JS-charts with embedded Latex?

Comment: How do I used latex-to-unicode as an external resource from jsdelivr? Also what is JS-charts? I couldn't find it.

Comment: For use as external resource with jsdelivr you need to build browser version and place it to github because directive `require` not supported yet. Clone repo as fork, build browser version, commit & push and find it on jsdelivr (https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/latex-to-unicode).

Comment: You question is very rare. This option is missing in almost all modern charts. I assumed you found and used some solution until you decided to use Echarts.

Comment: Gnuplot and Mathplotlib is answer, I understood.

Comment: Yea I generally use gnuplot/matplotlib but in this case I need to make a web app with javascript.

Comment: I make [issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/13256) to implement this feature but is very hard work.